# Semantic UI tab not styling

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, semantic-ui

I am following the usage guidelines exactly as explained on the Semantic UI page http://www.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab.html#/usage and placed the tab.min.css file into my CSS folder, and correctly linked it. When I run the page however, it looks nothing like the Semantic UI ones. Instead, it looks vertical and plain text like this:

Tab 1
Tab 2
Tab 3

This is the code I have now on my page where the tabs are needed.

```
<script>$('.tabular.menu .item').tab();
</script>

<div class="ui tabular menu" >
  <div class="item active" data-tab="ts-tab1">Tab 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-tab="ts-tab2">Tab 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-tab="ts-tab3">Tab 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-tab="ts-tab4">Tab 4</div>
  <div class="item" data-tab="ts-tab5">Tab 5</div>
  <div class="item" data-tab="ts-tab6">Tab 6</div>
</div>

<div class="ui tab active" data-tab="ts-tab1">
 example content
</div>

<div class="ui tab" data-tab="ts-tab2">
  example content

</div>
<div class="ui tab" data-tab="ts-tab3">
 example content

</div>
<div class="ui tab" data-tab="ts-tab4">
 example content

</div>
<div class="ui tab" data-tab="ts-tab5">
 example content

</div>
<div class="ui tab" data-tab="ts-tab6">
 example content

</div>
```

What am I missing? I am so frustrated as I've been trying to mess with it for a day now..thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your entire HTML page? You have loaded jQuery prior to executing the `$('.tabular.menu .item').tab()` code right?

Comment: When you go to dev tools network tab are any of the css or js scripts 404ing?  If you view source and click on links to included files, do they show up or 404 ?   Please include your entire HTML source, as well as a link to the page if possible.   Also include any custom jquery you have written.   Thanks

Comment: The `<script>` is placed before the HTML, so the browser will run it before rendering the dom. Is it wrapped in a `$(document).ready` handler? Other than this it looks like it should work

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this while researching the same issue while implementing the Tab in React. The problem for me was that the `tab.min.css` file didn't include the menu related styles, which are used for the tabular menu. Adding the related menu classes to the css resolved the issue.

Comment: Thanks but how do I do that? Is that a separate `import`? A pointer or code segment would be helpful.

Comment: @HansBouwmeester what I mean is that you need to look at the styles (by reference) that are being added by your Semantic Component (for example check the rendered HTML). Then find which of those style references are not in the stylesheets you have imported and manually add them. In my case, I looked at the Tab component and then added the menu related styles from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.4.1/components/menu.css manually to my own stylesheets as a workaround.